# How to save data with unique field in many-to-many relationship using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I am new in hibernate and I have next situation:

```
@Entity 
class Post {
    @Id id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ATag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    Set<Tag> tags;
}

@Entity 
class Tag {
    @Id Long id;
    String name;
}
```

table `tag` has constraint `unique` on the `name` field. If I save post object with tag which name already exists it will return error like:

```
Nov 25, 2014 9:23:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tags_name_key"
  Detail: Key (name)=(ert) already exists.
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

how can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [proper `equals` and `hashCode`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) implementations in your `Tag` class. Using the `name` property to distinguish between different Tags is a good idea.

Since `Post`.`tags` is a `Set`, it will discard duplicates prior to flushing the collection, so you shouldn't get the constraint violation.

```
@Entity 
public class Tag {

    @Id Long id;
    String name;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        HashCodeBuilder hcb = new HashCodeBuilder();
        hcb.append(name);
        return hcb.toHashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Tag)) {
            return false;
        }
        Tag that = (Tag) obj;
        EqualsBuilder eb = new EqualsBuilder();
        eb.append(name, that.name);
        return eb.isEquals();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose that your suggestion won't solve my problem because I don't need Tags with same names.

Comment: It won't help, it will not create new pos and ATag records avoiding new tag records

Answer (score 0):

Since the record you are trying to save already exists, you need to either call **update** or **saveOrUpdate** ... but that sort of depends on why you're trying to save a duplicate record in the first place? Are you trying to insert or just update an existing record?

Comment: I just want to save Post which can have several Tags. If I save new Post with new Tag it will save it, but if I save new Post with Tag which already exists it will cause an error.